# Can a denominator of fraction be multiplied by -1 without affecting the numerator ? and if so why?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I have been presented with a solution for solving trigonometric identities. However I would like to see further proof that one of the lines of work are valid. 
\begin{align*}
\frac{2\sin x\cos x}{1 + (\cos x)^2 - (\sin x)^2} & =  \frac{2\sin x\cos x}{1  - (\sin x)^2 + (\cos x)^2}\\
 & = \frac{2\sin x\cos x}{2(\cos x)^2}\\
 & = \frac{\sin x}{\cos x}\\
 & = \tan x
\end{align*}

As shown the denominator is multiplied by $-1$, however the numerator has not. Is this valid? And if so, why?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Will do, Cheers !

Comment: Great display name, RIP Futurama.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no multiplication by $-1$, only a reordering of the terms:
$$
1+(\cos x)^2-(\sin x)^2 = 1-(\sin x)^2+(\cos x)^2.
$$

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up, what a silly mistake !

Comment: I've done way worse (and will most likely still do). :)